# Is it important to preserve answers which don't solve the OP's issue but could help others?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223896/format-json-body-for-retrofit-from-single-string-value-without-model) today.

It received a pretty decent example straight away that unfortunately didn't solve *my* problem, however I think the answer would have been valid for some of the people discovering the question.

I told the poster that I tried his solution and it didn't help me... and he deleted the answer.

Because it's deleted I can't comment further to tell him I think he should have left the answer. He wasn't a newbie, I'm not really sure the rationale for deleting such answers, but seeing as there is no user-user messaging - Is there anything to be done in such a situation? Is it even important to preserve answers that might solve related searches?

Comment: Do you think a user could solve their problem by searching for yours and finding that answer? It would be useful if that is possible. If it fixes another problem people might not be likely to find it. Perceived incorrect or wrong answers (which comments suggest) can attract DV's so it might have been a way to prevent that. In general if the content has merit to other users it should remain.

Comment: It seems to be pretty clearly not solving the problem described in the question, so it being deleted seems entirely merited.  The user can post that solution to a problem that it actually solves if they feel its useful information.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was a reasonable enough solution that I tried it myself to see if it could be accepted, which is why I also thought it was worth keeping. As the poster mentioned, some API's can accept both formats. @Matt good point about DV's I guess that was the rationale for removing it and yes, I personally often find a solution on loosely-related questions

Comment: I personally never found "it wouldn't work" a great encouragement to keep an unhelpful answer around.  We do distinguish between "helpful" and "correct", you got the answer mark to select the latter.  You certainly don't *have* to vote it helpful.  And the poster likewise has no obligation to dig deeper.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear what you are saying @hans passant. I tried to imply that i had tried his idea already (i had) but he didn't understand and again told me to try it, so I was more direct

Comment: It's important to permit other answers that don't solve your particular problem, but you don't need to go out of your way to foster them.  In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c) that I asked,  the answer that solved the problem for me was actually not as useful/popular as one of the other answers.

Comment: Side note on your user to user communication: you can still ping the user with an @ username in a comment on your question. As the user has been participating in the thread he should be notified IIRC.

Comment: Voting to undelete this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38223920/230513).

Comment: I had an [answer like this once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22822491/1858225) that received several upvotes before I realized I'd misunderstood the question. (I've deleted it; I assume users with 10K+ rep can still see it, though, via the link?) I [asked on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262498/1858225) what to do and ended up [writing and answering my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24641865/1858225).

Comment: I also edited the original question to clarify it.

Comment: This is essentially the inverse of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266917/1432801 (my question). Conclusion: answers that aren't *the* answer do have value.

Comment: It would be nice if the OP could flag a question as "not the accepted answer, but still valuable" which would shield it either from downvotes or from rep loss as a result of downvotes.  That could remove the incentive for deleting such answers.  Or (even better) would (perhaps with the answerer's approval) shunt it off to a separate section of the page ("helpful comments" or "helpful additional info" or something).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I find that alternative answers are always very useful when I'm in need of help and am browsing through other people's questions. The fact is that the top answer only works for me 50% of the time and the alternative answers are great alternative ways to tackle the same problem.

Most of my use of Stackoverflow is doing a Google search trying to solve a problem. Google usually surfaces a bunch of SO questions, but these might not be exactly tackling the problem the way I need it. Alternative answers seem to be filling some of those gaps more often than not.

Comment: exactly - often related questions and "wrong" answers are all in the ballpark and help to paint the picture of the problem space that is highly valuable in identifying which of them is right.  When I understand the forest better, I can work with individual trees more effectively.

Answer (score 16):

You (mostly) can't control people from deleting their answers.  The answerer probably feared that your comment that their answer did not solve your problem would attract downvotes.

If you think the answer could help future users, you could ping the user on a different post they wrote, or invite them to chat and explain the situation.

Comment: I'd imagine that pinging on a different post would just add unrelated noise (which may seem mildly annoying)

Comment: @Sayse you're right, but there are limited other options besides inviting the user to chat (since many users do not use Chat at all).  You could always ping the user and delete your comment after 12/24 hours.

Comment: @Sayse I've had something similar happen to me on a different question about one of my deleted questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620330/nested-json-objects-in-keen-io#comment41309755_24620330

Comment: Just wanted to add that once OP gets [enough rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) he can vote to undelete the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you feel that a valuable Q&A has been lost because the Q and the A are mismatched, you can post an appropriate new Q and self-answer with the same content as the valuable answer that has been deleted. You probably should still attribute your new answer to the original deleted answer -- even if it's gone except to 10K+ members who can still see it.

@NickCardoso: Here is the content of the deleted answer by [Bartek Lipinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993204/bartek-lipinski) in case you want to self-answer:

> It does not necessarily create a json body, but your api might be able
>   to work with url encoded things
>
> ```
> @FormUrlEncoded
> @POST("foo/{fooId}/bars")
> Observable<Void> postBar(@Path("fooId") String styleId, @Field("bar") String bar);
> ```

Comment: I think this answer is valuable because of its overall message. The particulars in practice might be sketchy. OP isn't saying that the deleted answer was a *mismatch* for the question, and indeed was trying to point out that the answer might have been helpful for others *with the same question*. Therefore, the proper application of the main idea I think you're presenting here is not to post a new question (which would have to work hard to not be a duplicate of the original) but to just self-answer on the *same* question.

Comment: @JohnY. Self-(re)-posting the valuable deleted answer sounds good in this case. I'll post the deleted answer so Nick Cardoso has the content if he wants to repost.

Comment: This is a ridiculous cycle. The mismatched Q & A is important because those with the question don't know how to formulate the question correctly to find the answer. This is a problem of knowledge asymmetry that any Q&A site should adapt to, rather than adapting questions to answers. Nonsensical.