# Someone deleted their answer to my question, which probably solved the issue. What can I do about this?

Tags: support, deletion

I asked a question about pandas, a python library, and user @ayhan posted an answer that was probably correct. I did not have time to implement it or respond at the time, and then the user deleted the answer. What can I do about this?

Here's the link to my post: [No output with .duplicated in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818401/no-output-with-duplicated-in-pandas)

Here's the link to the user's page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/ayhan

Comment: _" What can I do about this?"_ In one word: Nothing.

Comment: It's pretty likely that the user realized there's a problem with their answer, and they either couldn't fix it or didn't have the time to correct it.

Comment: I thought someone hacked my account at the first glance...

Comment: If I wasn't so lazy I'd rename my account to @dorukayhan right about now.

Comment: A screenshot for your convenience: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JkRyl.png If you really think it solved your question you may replicate it as your own answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: maybe the poster discovered a fatal flaw in the answer and deleted it, pending further edits. I've done that once or twice, just to prevent downvotes in the mean time.

Comment: @RadLexus Yeah, sure. There are many reasons why this could happen. The essential is, that the OP can't do very much about it with less than 10k rep. Maybe we should scribble this up in a short answer.

Comment: I wonder why this question is getting 5 downvotes immediately ?

Comment: I'm not sure either. Thank you @πάνταῥεῖ, that screenshot is perfect.

Comment: Why did people downvote this question? Unless this is a duplicate this is a perfectly fine written meta question about a real world problem. Crazy.

Comment: @Trilarion There is no need to call out the user in question here which probably attracted some of the downvotes.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327489/2415822

Answer (score 3):

> What can I do about this?

Merely nothing with a reputation of less than 10k (if you have this you're privileged to see deleted posts and vote to undelete them).

Though you can ask a question at meta stack overflow (as you did right now), and see enough attention from +10k users that could vote to undelete the answer you desire.

But be aware the meta effect could also hit the question to be closed as off-topic<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup>
<sub>You should note there's already one close vote casted as the time I'm writing this:

*"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. 1"*</sub>

Comment: One could ask the guy who deleted the answer to consider undeleting it by commenting on one of his contributions, but probably not more than once, otherwise it could be seen as stalking.